# Ayuda con una consulta en linq

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

quiero realizar una clasificacion por asi decirlo de una lista que tengo, estoy tratando de realizarlo con linq.
bueno esto es lo que quiero..

Resultado.
Este la informacion con la que cuento.

```
Proveedor: Videmont
Cap. Morgan = $450.12
ET. Negra   = $620.32
Proveedor: HEB
Cap. Morgan = $400.50
ET. Negra   = $508.79
Proveedor: Alamo
Cap. Morgan = $300.48
ET. Negra   = $589.46
```

Quiero tomar los productos Cap. Morgan y ET. Negra, cuyo precio se el menor, de los proveedores.
y el resultado es este, viendolo asi simple.

```
Alamo: Morgan    = $300.48
HEB:   ET. Negra = $508.79
```

Este es el codigo con la que ya clasifique los datos.

```
  var prove2 = compra.GroupBy(x => x.Proveedor).Select(g => new
                {
                    Proveedor = g.FirstOrDefault().Proveedor,
                    Productos = g.Select(y => new {
                        Producto = y.Producto,
                        PrecioMenor = y.MenorPrecio
                    }),
                    CantidadCotizada = g.FirstOrDefault().CantidadCotizada,
                    MenosPrecio = g.Select(r => r.MenorPrecio).Min(),

                }).ToList();
```

El resultado lo dibuje en este esquema.

```
Proveedor 
|__ Productos
            |_Producto1
                      |_ Producto
                      |_ MenorPrecio

Videmont
|__ Cap. Morgan
|__ $450.12
|__ ET. Negra 
|__ $620.32
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera tomar los productos con menor precio de cada uno osea de Morgan y Et. Negra, con su respectivo proveedor.
espero alguien me oriente. gracias

Comment: Me gustaria ayudarte, pero no entiendo que quieres exactamente, buscas hacer una busqueda de Linq y de ahi obtener el producto de menor precio con su proveedor? eso es lo que quieres obtener?

Comment: Asi es, obtener los productos Cap. Morgan = $300.48
ET. Negra   = $589.46, con sus precios. del proveedor., y claro tambien el proveedor. viendolo asimplevista este seria el resultado.. Alamo: Morgan    = $300.48
HEB:   ET. Negra = $508.79 @EnriqueA.PineloNovelo

Comment: Yo no termino de entender el problema tampoco. Considera hacer un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mas facilmente.

Comment: Ejemplo como? del resultado, de la linea de codigo? -si es asi, este seria mi resultado: `Alamo: Morgan    = $300.48
HEB:   ET. Negra = $508.79`

Comment: @JuanL si has leido el enlace que te puse de [mcve], se trata de poner un ejemplo minimo con unas clases y datos de ejemplo, para poder compilarlas y probar cual es el problema.A parte de eso, tu consulta parece correcta, es decir, ver que te da como resultado el producto y su precio menor. En que exactamente estás teniendo problemas?

Comment: Quiero tomar, un producto de cada uno es decir, el morgan con el precio menor, y ET. Negra con el precio menor, independientemente de que sea de diferente proveedor, en la quieri solo los grupo. ya que me sigue mostrando los 4 proveedores con sus productos, y en si quiero solo los productos, Morgan y ET.Negra con el precio menor... @Pikoh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como no se exactamente cual es tu modelo de datos, no te puedo dar una solución exacta. Pero vamos a ver si esto te sirve.

En lugar de agrupar por Proovedor, como lo que te interesa son los precios mas baratos por producto, lo que debes hacer es agrupar por producto. Luego, simplemente obtienes el mínimo precio por producto.

Lo más complejo es obtener el proovedor de ese producto mas barato. Hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero una muy sencilla es simplemente buscar el registro cuyo precio coincida con el menor.

Resumiendo, sería algo asi:

```
var masbaratos = compra.GroupBy(x => x.Producto).Select(g => new
{
    Producto = g.Key,
    PrecioMenor = g.Min(x => x.MenorPrecio),
    Proveedor = g.Where(x => x.MenorPrecio == g.Min(y => y.MenorPrecio) && x.Producto==g.Key).First().Proveedor
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Si ese es el punto quiero obtener el proveedor de ese producto. pero voy a probar tu codigo. @Pikoh